# Aws Blockchain Template Error on stack creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, blockchain, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create stack to deploy fabric blockchain network on EC2, but I've always the same error

> The following resource(s) failed to create: [FabricEC2CommonStack]. .
>   Rollback requested by user. CREATE_FAILED AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
>   FabricEC2CommonStack Embedded stack
>   arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:>:stack/FabricStack-FabricEC2CommonStack-NNFUD6RJCZB1/<>
>   was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to
>   create: [EC2InstanceForDev].

I thought it was a problem with my EC2 Instance profile, but it seems correct. It has the policies to use ECR+S3. Thanks

Comment: Can you add the CloudFormation templates for both of the stacks?

Comment: I used the template given by AWS at this link
https://aws.amazon.com/it/blockchain/templates/getting-started/

Comment: Guessing this template: https://aws-blockchain-templates-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hyperledger/fabric/templates/simplenetwork/latest/hyperledger.template.yaml

Comment: You'll need to look at FabricEC2CommonStack to see why EC2InstanceForDev failed to create. It could be an issue unrelated to the templates themselves like EC2 instance quotas for your account

Comment: by any chance you solved this issue?